# Detecting an NSColorWell's changed selection

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nscolorwell

I have been looking at how to use an `NSColorWell` in my app, but there doesn't seem to be much documentation on it.

Is there any way to embed a colour picker (such as the `NSColorWell`/`NSColorPanel`) directly into my view? When clicking the well, it always presents a new colour picking window. Can this not be embedded somehow?

I have a custom `NSButton` class to which I am passing the colour from my `NSColorWell`. To do this, I am having to make the user pick a colour, then click a button to send this colour to my custom class. Is there a way of simply detecting when a new colour is selected directly from the color picker?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For problem 1, no, that's the system behaviour for an `NSColorWell`. Don't like it? make your own.

Problem 2 has two possible solutions.

Method 1: Connect the action from the color well to your object in IB and read the color of the color well via an outlet from your class. Any color change in the well will send a message to the selector of your choice.

Method 2: Add an object of your own as an observer to the `color` property

```
[colorwell addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"color" options:0 context:NULL];
```

then implement

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
```

Any color change will trigger that method.

Be sure to detach from the color well in `dealloc` or another breakdown method:

```
[colorwell removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"color"]
```

There's a way to do it with bindings as well, but these two are fine.

Comment: Method 2 works a charm, thanks! As for problem 1, I thought as much, not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the color panel problem, I was also looking for such a thing. The closes I could find was this one on [CocoaControls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/bfcolorpickerpopover). Unfortunately, this only works on 10.7+ (as it uses NSPopover) and it looks like it uses a private API.

Answer (score 0):

For swift 2 I use this code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var colorSelector: NSColorWell!

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()

        self.colorSelector.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "color", options: .New, context: nil)

    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(){
        super.viewDidDisappear()

        self.colorSelector.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath:"color")
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        print("keyPath=>\(keyPath)")

        if (keyPath! == "color") {
            print("object=>\(self.colorSelector.color)")
        } 
    }
```